# Webscraping elements with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

Im currently using beautiful soup to try and webscrape a website for data however the python module is reading the source code of the page. In the source code of the page the information i need isn't there however if i right click on the page in chrome and inspect element it is.

i was wondering if there was any way a python module could scrape the elements from a webpage and not the source code

In beautiful soup ive tried to search for the elements like  however they just dont come up or appear because  its searching in the source code. Im also not sure why or how it doesnt appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the contents are loaded by JavaScript, you can not get the data via ***Beautiful Soup***. In this situation, the ***[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)*** library is used as it is more useful and handy to extract the required dynamic contents.